# Function to find common high or low prices for a number of candles

Tags: mql4

Normally we use the function (iHigh) or (iLow) to find the highest or lowest price of a certain candle.
My question is, is there a way or function i can use to find a common price shared by a number of candles..lets say 10 previous candles...and use the returned values to draw a line of support or resistance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the highest high or the lowest low of a series of candles using [iHighest()](https://docs.mql4.com/series/ihighest) and [iLowest()](https://docs.mql4.com/series/ilowest). An example would be:

```
int index=iHighest(NULL,0,MODE_HIGH,20,4);
double highest=iHigh(NULL,0,index);
```

This example would find the highest high of the candles from bar 4 to 23.